# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double' of 'value'

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a date from firstPoint to the route, but when I try to add it, I get an error. How to solve this?

Error:
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double' of 'value')

route looks like:

```
[
    {
      "lat": 41.29251354457211,
      "lng": 69.28623834854497
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.2924753,
      "lng": 69.28618089999999
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.2924753,
      "lng": 69.28618089999999
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.2922043,
      "lng": 69.2857598
    },
]
```

firstPoint:

```
{
  lat: 41.29255161333333, 
  lng: 69.28619297, 
  Date: 2023:05:18 11:49:28, 
  indexInAllRoute: 0
}
```

Code:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> interpolateTime(List<Map<String, dynamic>> allRoute, Map<String, dynamic> firstPoint, Map<String, dynamic> secondPoint, double speed) {
  debugLog(interpolateTime, 'AllRoute', allRoute, false);

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> route = List.from(allRoute);

  if (route. Length < 2) {
    return [];
  }

  route[firstPoint['indexInAllRoute']]["Date"] = firstPoint['Date'];

  route[firstPoint['indexInAllRoute']]['Type'] = "Real";
  route[secondPoint['indexInAllRoute']]['Date'] = secondPoint['Date'];
  route[secondPoint['indexInAllRoute']]['Type'] = "Real";
}
```

Comment: On a first look, your first json has quotation marks around all string parts **lat**, etc while the second one has not. 
So for the second one the right side value of **Date** might get interpreted as a double ( the numbers *2023:05:18 11:49:28* )